# Google Data Studio Scheduled Email doesn't work for Additional Recipients

Tags: looker-studio

As described at https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9263641, there is now the Scheduled Email feature for Google Data Studio Reports.

We tried to set up a scheduled email in my organization and we noticed that the emails do not work for anyone except the person who set up the schedule.  All emails have been verified to be correct and all users receiving the email have access to the underlying data source(s) (not sure if that matters though).

What do we need to do to get the scheduled email working for additional recipients?  Even if it was only 1 other email, we could set up an email group and handle getting it to everyone that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually an issue, after further investigation these emails were being caught by my company's spam filter.  Once I whitelisted data-studio-noreply@google.com, I was able to receive the messages.